# Background service with CDI

Tags: java, cdi

I have a Java SE application with CDI/Weld (started with `org.jboss.weld.environment.se.StartMain`, without any application server).
What is the proper way to start a background service inside it?

I've tried creating a `@Singleton` bean which observes the `ContainerInitialized` event (like below) but I'm not sure when the container will destroy this service bean. Is it safe? Is there a better way?

```
@Singleton
public class BackgroundService {

    public void onStart(@Observes ContainerInitialized event) {
        // starting other threads etc.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would use `@ApplicationScoped` not `@Singleton`.  The lifecycle will shutdown the object when the container shuts down.  If you want to start a thread, this would be a likely choice to put the code.

It is not asynchronous by default, so you'll need to start the thread yourself.